# Spring do not recognize custom keys-to-sanitize, instead it is referring to default ones

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

It seems that Spring is not reading the customized keys for sanitizing the values.(it is only referring to default ones)

I have added below properties in `application.properties` file

```
endpoints.env.id=env
endpoints.env.sensitive=true
endpoints.env.enabled=true
endpoints.env.keys-to-sanitize=port
```

After starting the app and navigating to /env endpoint I am getting below response

```
"endpoints.env.keys-to-sanitize":{"value":"port","origin":"URL 
[file:./application.properties]:40:32"},"endpoints.env.sensitive":{"value":"true","origin":"URL 
[file:./application.properties]:41:25"},"endpoints.env.enabled":{"value":"true","origin":"URL 
[file:./application.properties]:42:23"},"password":{"value":"******","origin":"URL 
[file:./application.properties]:43:10"} ,
"management.port":{"value":"8081","origin":"URL [file:./application.properties]:36:17"}
```

Notice that port are still visible and the password is masked with ****.

Am I missing something. My requirement is to add few more keys to hide their values.

Comment: What's the spring-boot version? If you are on version 2 and above the properties that you're using have been deprecated for a while https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#spring-boot-actuator

Comment: I am using SpringBootVersion - 2.1.18

Comment: WIll Try with new properties

Comment: It worked :) .However It was not mentioned anywhere on spring documentation site.  @Marcos Could you please post it as a answer. I would accept that. It can be helpful for other people facing similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Spring Boot version 2 and above, the properties have changed.
You can follow the [Actuator Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#spring-boot-actuator) for more details.

[image: Migration Guide]